In .snakemake/singularity/, how to know which simg file corresponding to which docker image?
In my snakemake pipeline, multiple docker images are used. Here is what I got in .snakemake/singularity/:
206ecba08103dc72b70b7a423ca7c4e2.simg
2a79fd96f10690c6de61b11dd1f67b37.simg
487b527f49600892f83f30551f04b0bf.simg
707a6a013c0f2b6e8b0c1342c00813f0.simg
9165d245ffa2587da2c1e396259e2770.simg
a3ac4d78587ba2595286f5894581b3af.simg
f9cb4ca022d47072315843839a0fe61c.simg
Is there a way to quickly identify which simg file corresponds to which docker image?

When a rule gets executed, snakemake will report which singularity image is getting activated.  You could probably hash the contents of the docker file to recreate the filenames?
